# merging two arrays of tuples

Tags: swift, swift4

I have two arrays that I want to merge.

```
typealias PointTuple = (day: Double, mW: Double)
let weightsMeasured: [PointTuple] = [(0.0, 31.98),(1.0, 31.89),(2.0, 31.77),(4.0, 31.58),(6.0, 31.46)]
let weightsCalulated: [PointTuple] = [(day: 0.0, mW: 31.966637931034484), (day: 1.0, mW: 31.87793103448276), (day: 2.0, mW: 31.789224137931036), (day: 3.0, mW: 31.700517241379313), (day: 4.0, mW: 31.611810344827585), (day: 5.0, mW: 31.523103448275862), (day: 6.0, mW: 31.434396551724138), (day: 7.0, mW: 31.345689655172414), (day: 8.0, mW: 31.256982758620691), (day: 9.0, mW: 31.168275862068967), (day: 10.0, mW: 31.079568965517243), (day: 11.0, mW: 30.990862068965516), (day: 12.0, mW: 30.902155172413792), (day: 13.0, mW: 30.813448275862068), (day: 14.0, mW: 30.724741379310345), (day: 15.0, mW: 30.636034482758621), (day: 16.0, mW: 30.547327586206897), (day: 17.0, mW: 30.458620689655174), (day: 18.0, mW: 30.36991379310345), (day: 19.0, mW: 30.281206896551723), (day: 20.0, mW: 30.192499999999999), (day: 21.0, mW: 30.103793103448275), (day: 22.0, mW: 30.015086206896552), (day: 23.0, mW: 29.926379310344828), (day: 24.0, mW: 29.837672413793104), (day: 25.0, mW: 29.74896551724138), (day: 26.0, mW: 29.660258620689653)]
```

The weightsCalculated array is always 27 tuples (days 0.0 to 26.0). The weightsMeasured array can be 0 - 27 tuples.

The result should be that the existing mW values in weightsCalculated are replaced with the mW values in weightsMeasured. So in this example:

```
[(day: 0.0, mW: 31.98 , (day: 1.0, mW: 31.89 , (day: 2.0, mW: 31.77 , (day: 3.0, mW: 31.700517241379313), (day: 4.0, mW: 31.58 , (day: 5.0, mW: 31.523103448275862), (day: 6.0, mW: 31.46 , (day: 7.0, mW: 31.345689655172414), (day: 8.0, mW: 31.256982758620691), (day: 9.0, mW: 31.168275862068967), (day: 10.0, mW: 31.079568965517243), (day: 11.0, mW: 30.990862068965516), (day: 12.0, mW: 30.902155172413792), (day: 13.0, mW: 30.813448275862068), (day: 14.0, mW: 30.724741379310345), (day: 15.0, mW: 30.636034482758621), (day: 16.0, mW: 30.547327586206897), (day: 17.0, mW: 30.458620689655174), (day: 18.0, mW: 30.36991379310345), (day: 19.0, mW: 30.281206896551723), (day: 20.0, mW: 30.192499999999999), (day: 21.0, mW: 30.103793103448275), (day: 22.0, mW: 30.015086206896552), (day: 23.0, mW: 29.926379310344828), (day: 24.0, mW: 29.837672413793104), (day: 25.0, mW: 29.74896551724138), (day: 26.0, mW: 29.660258620689653)]
```

Is there an 'easy' way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single `map` to achieve your calls. You call `map` on `weightCalculated`, which you know for sure will contain an entry for each day, then check if `weightsMeasured` contains an entry for the same day or not. If there is a measurement, return the measurement, otherwise return the calculated value.

```
let mergedWeights = weightsCalculated.map({ todayCalculated->PointTuple in
    if let todayMeasured = weightsMeasured.first(where: { $0.day == todayCalculated.day}) {
        return todayMeasured
    } else {
        return todayCalculated
    }
})
```

Or you can even write this as a one liner using the nil-coalescing operator to return the measured value if it is found and the calculated value otherwise:

```
let mergedWeights = weightsCalculated.map({ todayCalculated in return weightsMeasured.first(where: { $0.day == todayCalculated.day}) ?? todayCalculated })
```

When trying out the above code bear in mind that you had a typo in the variable name `weightCalculated`, which I corrected in my code.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why (day: 1.0, mW: 31.98) gets stored as (day: 1.0, mW: 31.890000000000001)? Is there a way to store it as xx.xx?

Comment: the `return` keyword in your second sample is redundant